# Is a bounded function always the Hilbert transform of some other function?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Given $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, does there always exist a $g$ (in some space) such that 
\begin{equation*}
Hg=f,
\end{equation*} 
where $Hg$ is the Hilbert transform of $g$ ? In other words, is the Hilbert transform defined for $BMO$ functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hilbert transform [is an anti-involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Inverse_transform), meaning $H(H(u))=-u$. This is easiest to observe on the Fourier side, where $H$ is the  multiplication by $-i\operatorname{sign}\omega$, hence  $H^2$ multiplies by $-1$.

Thus, $g=-Hf$ does the job. The function $g$ is generally not in $L^\infty$, but it [belongs to BMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Hilbert_transform_of_bounded_functions).

Comment: It's worth remarking that some work is needed to show that $H(g)=f$. For one, it's not obvious how to define the Hilbert transform of BMO function, which need not belong to $L^{\infty}$, as you remark. But based on the OP's question statement, s/he doesn't seemed concerned with this point.

Comment: Thank you, Normal Human and Matt. 
Yes. As far as I know, the anti-involution property of $H$ is proved on $L^p$ spaces, but since our BMO function need not be in $L^{\infty}$, we should be able to say that the domain of definition of $H$ extends to BMO. If you know a source for this, can you point it out to me? 
P.S.: I have edited the question since your answers.

Comment: @RR You can search for "Hilbert transform maps BMO to itself" and find a few sources. The $\mathcal H^1$-BMO duality enables this. Since you are in one dimension, the fact that Hilbert transform maps the Hardy space to itself is a consequence of the definition of the Hardy space in terms of holomorphic functions.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig ^

Comment: Got it, thanks.